# Google Apps Script Why it only searches for one (first) attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I have two codes, the first of which works and shows all attachments and the second shows only the first. "getAttachmentAndMessage" is used by several of my scripts so I need to have it in a separate function in order not to duplicate my configuration. Please help.

```
//this function get me all attachments
//this function is just an example of how I built my code below; 
function searchEmailsData(){
  var search = GmailApp.search('in:inbox newer_than:3d');
  var threads = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(search);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thread = threads[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < thread.length; j++) {
      var message = thread[j];
      var attachments = message.getAttachments();

      for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {        
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        Logger.log(attachment.getName());
      }
    }
  }
}

//this functions get me only first attachment but I need all of them;
function searchEmailsData2(){
  var search = GmailApp.search('in:inbox newer_than:3d');
  var threads = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(search);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thread = threads[i];    
    var obj = getAttachmentAndMessage(thread);    
    Logger.log(obj[1].getName())
  }
}

function getAttachmentAndMessage(thread){ 

  for (var j = 0; j < thread.length; j++) {
    var message = thread[j];

    var attachments = message.getAttachments();

    for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
      var attachment = attachments[k];
      var obj = [message, attachment];

      return obj;     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what the issue is here. It would help if you add an explanation of what's not working properly, what the current outcome is and what you would expect.

Comment: Your `getAttachmentAndMessage` function only returns a single attachment - the first one it finds. So... don't do that.

Comment: As said tehhowch my getAttachmentAndMessage function return only single attachment, what I need is to return all attachments like function searchEmailsData

Comment: @vipmaciej You are passing a `thread` to your `getAttachmentAndMessage()` function. What do you expect it to return? The first message the thread has plus all of its attachments? Or rather every message it contains plus every attachment each of them contains? Cheers

Comment: I expect every message in thread plus every attachment each of them contains. Like it is in function searchEmailsData()

Comment: @vipmaciej Hey, I have published an answer that may be helpful to you. Please let me know whether it accomplishes what you expect from that function. Cheers

Comment: It didn't work: "The undefined method "getName" cannot be called"

Answer (score 0):

In order to return not the first attachment but rather all of them, you can modify the `getAttachmentAndMessage()` function as follows:

```js
function getAttachmentAndMessage(thread) { 
  var results = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < thread.length; j++) {
    var message = thread[j];
    var attachments = message.getAttachments();

    var obj = {'message': message, 'attachments': attachments};
    results.push(obj);
  }

  return results;
}
```

The above will return a list of objects, in which each objects contains a property `message`, and a property `attachments` (which is a list of attachments).

In order to return a list containing **only** the attachments in the thread, you can use the following variation of the code above:

```js
function getAttachmentAndMessage(thread) { 
  var results = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < thread.length; j++) {
    var message = thread[j];
    var attachments = message.getAttachments();

    results = results.concat(attachments);
  }

  return results;
}
```

#### Your original code

In your original `getAttachmentAndMessage()` code, you were using a `return` statement inside of the for loop. That means that upon finding the first message (first iteration of the outer loop) and upon finding its first attachment (first iteration of the inner loop) the function would simply return one value, which is a list containing the first message and its first attachment.

Comment: It didn't work: "The undefined method "getName" cannot be called"

Comment: @vipmaciej There isn't a getName method call in this answer?

Comment: @vipmaciej Your line `Logger.log(obj[1].getName())` in your original question (inside the `searchEmailsData2()` function  seems to be the one causing the issue you are describing. Consider replacing it for the following `Logger.log(obj)` to log the whole list returned by the function, or `Logger.log(obj[0])` to log the first item of the list returned. Cheers

Comment: this Logg is not a problem in itself. If I use the searchEmailsData function I get it                 
GmailAttachment * X (depends how many attachments I have) 
When I used your code I get [{attachments=[GmailAttachment, GmailAttachment, GmailAttachment, GmailAttachment], message=GmailMessage}]
[{attachments=[GmailAttachment, GmailAttachment], message=GmailMessage}]
[{attachments=[GmailAttachment], message=GmailMessage}]
[{attachments=[GmailAttachment], message=GmailMessage}]

Comment: @vipmaciej I have edited with code that does what you just asked for. Let me know if that works for you now. Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't know how to get the name of all attachments

Comment: Hey @vipmaciej . The code I published after my edit, returns a list of attachments. In order to get the name of these attachments and log them, you can use the following code: `var attachments = getAttachmentAndMessage(thread); var attachmentNames = atachments.map(function(a) { a.getName() }); Logger.log(attachmentNames);`

Comment: everywhere is null

Comment: the problem is not solved, if anyone knows the answer please help

Comment: Hello again @vipmaciej. Exuse me - the code on my last comment had a small error. It should be as follows: `var attachments = getAttachmentAndMessage(thread); var attachmentNames = atachments.map(function(a) { return a.getName() }); Logger.log(attachmentNames);`. Please also be aware that the `getAttachmentAndMessage()` function in my answer takes, in fact, an array of messages. That is, if you have a `Thread` object *t*, you have to call the function as follows: `getAttachmentAndMessage(t.getMessages())`. Also, please know that some attachments may be nameless (such as embedded images).